# Do C++ objects have the class's static methods?

Tags: c++

I have a class that I'm refactoring it and would like to add a helper function to eliminate some code duplication in both static and non-static methods, so the helper function must be static. When I go to call the helper function from inside the non-static method, will I need to use the double colon notation, MyClass::helper_function(x, y, z), the arrow notation, this->helper_function(x, y, z), or just helper_function(x, y, z)? If the helper function was public would you be able to access it from an instance with the dot notation, myObject.helper_function(x, y, z)? I'll try it out in a couple of minutes, and I'm sure I'll figure it out, but I thought it was a good gedankenexperiment to try to figure out what will happen.
Should I just make the helper function not a member of the class at all, but just put it in the class's .cpp file to make it accessible to the class's methods? What is the best practice?

Comment: Note that if you use something like `MyClass().helper_function(x, y, z)` a `MyClass` temporary is actually constructed (unless removed by optimisation under the "as if" rule) even though it's not used by the `static` `helper_function`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## All three formats work.

- `MyClass::helper_function` -  this is a Qualified Name. The class name is looked up first, finds the current class, and then the static method is found in the class.
- `helper_function` - this is an unqualified name. it will be looked up in the class scope first, before the surrounding scope would be tried. But since `helper_function` is a static method in the class,  no further searches are done
- `this->helper_function` - This is the most unusual of all. The `this` pointer has type `MyClass*`, so the search is restricted to `MyClass`. But once `helper_function` is found, it turns out that the `this` pointer isn't actually needed. That doesn't invalidate the name lookup.

## Class member or not?

A `static` helper function may access other class members, in particular `private` members. This includes private constructors, private destructors, private nested types, constants, etc. If you need one of them, a static method is the only reasonable choice.

Comment: So it sounds like the most efficient way would be to use the second form.

Comment: @sidney_h: Efficiency isn't really important - it's just compile time. Readability matters far more, and that's subjective. But the third form is misleading as it looks like a non-static member, so that's widely considered not so readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access static methods by way of the `this` pointer and the `.` or `->` notation.